# I can't use z-index to put something in the backgorund

Tags: html, css

```
www.codepen.io/BlueRedOne/pen/rOpjxN
```

If you hover over Musikfest 2017 you will see it and i has the z-index on 0 and the navigation on 1 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give every element with `z-index` a `position: relative`.

`z-index` won't work without any form of `position` applied to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `z-index, position` to `nav ul` like this: **[Demo](http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/bVaqBN)**

```
nav ul{
    margin-left: -40px;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 9999;
position: relative
}
```

You can remove all other z-index which used. Hope this is what you want !

Answer (score 0):

give your `<ul>` which is the pulldown `position: relative;` then it will above your content